# Symfony2 - why can't Symonfy load my YAML configuration

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I am trying to load a custom YAML config file within a bundle, which errors out, saying:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration

---

The custom YAML config file:

```
#AppBundle/Resources/config/myconfig.yml
myapp: myvalue
```

The configuration file:

```
//AppBundle/DependencyInjection/MyConfiguration.php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use ...

class MyConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface {

    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $treeBuilder->root('myapp')->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }

}
```

The extension file:

```
//AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use ...

class AppExtension extends Extension {

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $this->processConfiguration(new MyConfiguration(), $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );

        $loader->load('myconfig.yml');
    }   

}
```

The full error message:

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 399:
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "myapp" (in C:\my_project\src\AppBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\myconfig.yml). Looked for namespace "myapp", found none

---

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use the `myapp` custom alias.

#### First solution: use the default alias

Symfony uses the underscored version of the bundle name by default (e.g. `AcmeTestBundle` will be transformed to `acme_test`).

Considering your bundle namespace, the `app` alias will be the default.

You can change this code:

```
$treeBuilder->root('myapp')->end();
```

into this:

```
$treeBuilder->root('app')->end();
```

And then use the `app` key in your configuration file.

This is the preferred solution, as it makes your configuration match your bundle names. If the configuration name doesn't suit you, maybe it's because the bundle is not named correctly!

#### Alternative solution: keep your custom alias

You may have only one bundle in your app, which is called `AppBundle` because you don't intend to reuse this bundle in any other project. If you still want to use a custom alias (`myapp` instead of `app`), here is the way to go:

```
<?php
//AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use ...

class AppExtension extends Extension {

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // ...
    }


    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'myapp';
    }
}
```

As Symfony will not like this alias by default, change your Bundle file as well:

```
<?php
// AppBundle/AppBundle.php
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        if (null === $this->extension) {
            $extension = $this->createContainerExtension();

            if (null !== $extension) {
                if (!$extension instanceof ExtensionInterface) {
                    throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Extension %s must implement Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface.', get_class($extension)));
                }

                $this->extension = $extension;
            } else {
                $this->extension = false;
            }
        }

        if ($this->extension) {
            return $this->extension;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed `myapp` to `app`, still the same error. I also removed the `my` prefix from the `Configuration` class and `config` yaml file. (changes are in repo)

Comment: Dumping the the `$rootNode` in ihe `getConfigTreeBuilder` shows that the tree is being built...

Comment: I see your problem. It's because you try to use the `app` parameter directly in the bundle config. Using it in `app/config/config.yml` will work with the solution I provided. Is it because you want to add some default values for your bundle? In that case, you would have to use the features of the Tree Builder: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#adding-node-definitions-to-the-tree

Comment: Therein lies another issue -- yes, I am trying to define values pertaining to my bundle. They will not be overridden/modified, so I wouldn't consider them "default", as they are just the values I am setting... The purpose of these config values is to hold the data that is currently in a bunch of custom annotations for the attributes of my doctrine entities... i.e. I am moving all my custom doctrine annotation to a config file. So the said "other issue" is whether I am taking the right approach by putting the config in the bundle vs the global config file

Comment: I was thinking again to your issue. And I think you should use default configuration for your bundle, defining the configuration tree instead of your `config.yml` file of your bundle. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#default-and-required-values